# jQuery slideToggle only if other divs are hidden

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I am new to jQuery and Javascript and am having a problem with slideToggle. I have a website with a body of text that is visible when the page loads, below that is 3 li items. Each li item when clicked will open a hidden div to reveal its content.

What I want is the body text to slideToggle closed and stay closed as long as any of the hidden divs are visible. Right now, the body text toggles each time any of the li items is clicked.

Here is my html

```
<div class="dropdown-container-tv">
<h1>TV Commercials</h1>
[wooslider autoslide="false" slide_page="tv-commercials" slider_type="slides" limit="15" thumbnails="default" order="ASC" order_by="date"] 
<a class="close-dropdown" id="close-tv" href="#non">Close playback window</a>
</div><!-- end dropdown -->

<div class="dropdown-container-sales">
<h1>Sales/Web Videos</h1>
[wooslider autoslide="false" slide_page="sales-videos" slider_type="slides" limit="15" thumbnails="default" order="ASC" order_by="date"]
<a class="close-dropdown" id="close-sales" href="#non">Close playback window</a>
</div><!-- end dropdown -->

<div class="dropdown-container-radio">
<h1>Radio Spots</h1>
[wooslider autoslide="false" slide_page="radio-spots" slider_type="slides" limit="15" thumbnails="default" order="ASC" order_by="date"]
<a class="close-dropdown" id="close-radio" href="#non">Close playback window</a>
</div><!-- end dropdown -->

<div class="copy-container">
<div class="content-header">
<h1>Our Razor-Sharp Work</h1>
</div>
Beard Boy delivers:
<ul class="full-width-list">
<li>Agency-experienced professionals who come up with creative advertising solutions that work.</li>
<li>Skilled producers adept at keeping costs low while giving you more spot for your money.</li>
<li>Hollywood and Southern California-based actors, voice talent, directors, editors and composers that bring added value to your project.</li>
<li>A track record of success writing and producing over 600 projects for all kinds of clients, all across America.</li>
</ul>
</div>
<ul class="portfolio-links">
<li><a class="tv" id="dropdown-tv" href="#non">TV Commercials</a></li>
<li><a class="radio" id="dropdown-radio" href="#non">Radio Spots</a></li>
<li><a class="sales" id="dropdown-sales" href="#non">Sales/Web Videos</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here is the jQuery

```
(function($){

    /* trigger when page is ready */
    $(document).ready(function(){

        /* slideToggle Dropdown */
        $('#dropdown').on('click',function(){

              $('.dropdown-container').slideToggle();

        });

        $('#close').on('click',function(){

              $('.dropdown-container').slideToggle();

        });

        /* Tv */
        $('#dropdown-tv').on('click',function(){

              $('.dropdown-container-tv, .copy-container').slideToggle();

        });

        $('#close-tv').on('click',function(){

              $('.dropdown-container-tv, .copy-container').slideToggle();

        });

        /* Radio */
        $('#dropdown-radio').on('click',function(){

              $('.dropdown-container-radio, .copy-container').slideToggle();

        });

        $('#close-radio').on('click',function(){

              $('.dropdown-container-radio, .copy-container').slideToggle();

        });

        /* Sales */
        $('#dropdown-sales').on('click',function(){

              $('.dropdown-container-sales, .copy-container').slideToggle();

        });

        $('#close-sales').on('click',function(){

              $('.dropdown-container-sales, .copy-container').slideToggle();

        });
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can u please create a jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com playground?

Comment: Use `if($(selector).css('display')=='none')` to check is hidden or not

Comment: I figured it out with .is(':visible'). Thanks for your replies though, and sorry I did not get back to you earlier.